# Smooth scroll to ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this smooth scroll script on my website. I'm trying to make the smooth scroll, scroll to the target ID **but stop about 20px before the ID**.

This is my code:

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

I tried changing the `target.offset` but this didn't work. Is this possible?

Comment: `scrollTop: target.offset().top - 20` would do that i guess?

Comment: have you tried `target.offset().top-20`?

Comment: Excellent! I tried Jai's already that didn't work. Spluf attaching the -20 to the top did it. Thanks!

Comment: honestly, I can't see the difference between my comment and @Jai's, except for the spaces, but glad i could help :).

Comment: @Spluf Me neither but that one jumped to the target ID and yours didn't. :)